# Why does one the presence of one Import statement break another?

Tags: javascript, three.js, importerror

I have a JavaScript file with the following two `import` statements at the top of it:

```
import { FbxLoader } from "./ThreeJs/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader.js";
import * as Three from "./ThreeJs/src/Three.js";
```

When I load this into a browser I get `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`.  However, if I comment out the 1st `import` this error goes away but yet it looks like it's referring to the 2nd `import` since it makes reference to "three"!

If I swap the two `imports` around, the browser console still reports the same error on the same line!

What's going on here?  The files definitely exist, the paths to them are definitely correct.  If I make one of the file names incorrect I get a different (404) error in the console so it shouldn't be a bad path issue.

Comment: Presumably the non-browser-compatible import appears in FBXLoader.js or one of its dependencies. Note the second import doesn’t mention three (with a lower case t) at all.

Comment: Does that mean I should be looking in `FBXLoader.js` or one of its dependencies for another import alias named `three`?  There actually is one in `FBXLoader.js` with that exact casing (as in the error message).  I've just noticed the Console actually has `localhost/:1` against it rather than `MyJavaScriptFile.js:1` - no idea what that means now but I assume the `:1` means line 1 in `FBXLoader.js` now.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: I've been through `FBXLoader.js` and its dependencies (`NURBSCurve.js` and `NURBSUtils.js`) and changed each of their import statements' `from` from `three` to `'../../../src/Three.js'` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Correction - for `FBXLoader.js` `../../../../src/Three.js` and the other two `../../../src/Three.js` - but still the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THREE.FBXLoader depends on the three.js library, and [uses its own import](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/53c642e6905a1e53b0dd1c37ce14ec46f8b8fdc2/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader.js#L43) to obtain those dependencies. That `"three"` import is a module specifier — not a full path — as of threejs r156, and is meant to be resolved by a bundler or build tool.

Because you don't appear to be using a bundler or build tool here, the next best thing is to create an [Import Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap) pointing imports of `"three"` to the location of that file in your own project. The three.js [installation guide](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation) explains this in more detail – where it refers to a CDN, you could use local paths in your project instead.